# Rails variable in model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, model

In my controller, I have this:

```
user.save
if user.leveled_up==true
    flash[:notice]="HOOOORAY!!!"
end
```

and in my model I have:

```
before_save :check_xp

# ....

def leveled_up=(leveled_up)
        @leveled_up=leveled_up
        if @leveled_up==true
            self.statpoints+=5 
            hp=max_hp
        end
    end

    def leveled_up
        @leveled_up
    end

    private 
    def check_xp
        leveled_up=false
        case self.xp
        when 0..999
            self.level=1
        when 1000..2999
            leveled_up=true if self.level==1
            self.level=2
        when 3000..4999
            leveled_up=true if self.level==2
            self.level=3
        when 5000..9999
            leveled_up=true if self.level==3
            self.level=4

# ...

        end

    end
```

But this isn't working. Even if the User leveled up the function leveled_up returns false...

I must be doing something wrong...

Thanks!!

Comment: So what's the problem (more specifically than 'it isn't working')? Is it that the user just isn't seeing "HOORAY", you're getting an exception somewhere, or something else?

Comment: Chris, the hooray isn't displaying (there's a function to display in view) and 

if @leveled_up==true
                self.statpoints+=5 
                hp=max_hp
        end
isn't running... (never)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here leveled_up=false is not a method call. You actually created a local variable called leveled_up, it has nothing to do with the method. 
to call the method, use

```
self.leveled_up
```